# CiviMail User Information Not Displayed

Tags: civimail, joomla, activities

When I add a person to the CiviCRM "Assigned to" section, that person receives an e-mail. However, the data in the tables containing the user information does not appear, instead the code is output. I would like information about the cause and solution.

With Contact(s) name_18606
Created By  name_78220
Reported By name_78220
Assigned to name_78220

[image]

Joomla,  CiviCRM 5.29.0.

Comment: Can you check the contact page if the display name are set correclty?

Comment: Where do I check this out. There is no problem with viewing anywhere in CRM. This is a problem only when you send mail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have civicase enabled and have the setting Redact Activity Emails turned on. Under Admin - CiviCase - CiviCase Settings.

Comment: It was not effective. I activated. I changed the "Redact Activity Email" option to Default and the problem was fixed. Thank you so much.